# material-ui tab conpment Too slow to switch

Tags: material-ui

I have a problem in switching  component. It's too slow to switch animation, there are more delays than 1000ms.
My Component structure looks like this:

```
<div>
    <Tabs
        value={value}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        >
            <Tab label="Item One" />
            <Tab label="Item Two" />
     </Tabs>
      {value === 0 && <TabContainer>Item One</TabContainer>}
</div>
```

The  component is a complex component, where there are many data needs to be displayed.
I want the < Tab > component to complete the switching animation immediately, instead of waiting to happen with the < TabContainer > component.

Comment: I have the same issue. Were you able to solve?

Comment: I've noticed that performance is bad specifically on Chrome mobile. I've tried using various techniques to improve performance, e.g. memo and useCallback, but nothing helped. I also tried using ToggleButtonGroup instead, but observed similar lag. Interestingly, after selecting a text field, both Tabs or ToggleButtonGroup suddenly work fast.